# Hibernate, how to skip collection

Tags: hibernate

This is a table structure:

```
<class name="test.Book" table="book" >
  <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
  <id column="id" name="id" type="int" unsaved-value="-1">
    <generator class ="increment"/>  
  </id>
  <property column="title" name="title" type="string" not-null="false" />
  <property column="description" name="description" type="string" not-null="false" />
  <list name="chapters"  table="bookChapters" cascade="persist">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
    <key column="bookChapter_id"  />
    <list-index column="rank"/>
    <many-to-many column="chapter_id" class="test.Chapter" />
  </list>
</class>
```

Every time when I get the Book it has collection of chapters:

```
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Book.class, id);
List<Book> bookList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(crit);
```

Sometimes I need a Book without collection of chapters. How to do this with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

A book has chapters. If it has no chapter, the collection will be empy. That's what you want. It allows iterating through the chapters by doing

```
for (Chapter chapter : book.getChapters()) {
    ...
}
```

instead of

```
if (book.getChapters() != null) {
    for (Chapter chapter : book.getChapters()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It allows testing if the book has chapters by doing

```
if (!book.getChapters().isEmpty())
```

rather than by doing

```
if (book.getChapters() != null && !book.getChapters.isEmpty())
```

`null` is evil. You want to avoid null collections like the plague, because they cause bugs, and make the code less readable.

Comment: I don't need to fetch chapters from DB, i.e. it doesn't matter how many chapters some book has I don't need it.

Comment: With your nickname, you should have understood that: the collections are loaded *lazily* by default. So if you don't access the collection of chapters, hibernate won't load the chapters from the database. Only if you call some method on the collection (size(), iterator(), whatever), hibernate will load the chapters.

Comment: correct, but I have different default mode `<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">`
So, can I turn lazy mode to "true" in some cases?

Comment: I've tried `crit.setFetchMode("chapters", FetchMode.LAZY);` but chapters still fetched.

Comment: I'm not really used to xml mapping anymore. I only use annotations. But are you sure they're not loaded from the second-level cache, since you have specified `<cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>` on your mapping of the collection? Is the criteria you're showing the actual criteria you're using to load the books?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment on the default mode. If an association is eagerly fetched by default, it will always be eagerly fetched, and nothing will be able to switch it back to lazy. If an association is lazily fetched by default, you can still load it eagerly using a query with a fetch mode. So you shot yourself in the foot by setting the fetch mode to non-lazy by default.